# Why does alt+left arrow go into tty now? That's a chrome shortcut for 'back' and it keeps taking me to tty or login screen

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I'm using 18.04.1 LTS. I looked at the related questions, but they seem to suggest that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is also affected and somehow related, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Does it only happen for chrome? It's back for many apps, what happens in your file manager or firefox, ect?

Comment: [No longer happens for me](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/520546) after installing all the updates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known bug.  See [Alt+left/right arrows switch between tty consoles (Gnome Shell vanishes), cannot disable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146) for details.

For what it's worth, the same thing happens in Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

This command solves my problem.

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

Without argument, kbd_mode prints the current keyboard mode (RAW, MEDIUMRAW or XLATE). With argument, it sets the keyboard mode as indicated:

-s: scancode mode (RAW),

-k: keycode mode (MEDIUMRAW),

-a: ASCII mode (XLATE),

-u: UTF-8 mode (UNICODE).

Source:

`man kbd_mode`

Comment: Kindly edit your question and explain what exactly this command does and how it solves the issue.

Comment: Hi,, Read first 10 lines.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/kbd_mode.htm

Comment: That is exactly the point. You have to look elsewhere to know what the answer does. Everything should be in the answer. The answer should be self contained.

Comment: however it solve my problem. that's why I comment here.

Comment: I had this when pressing the "windows" aka meta button, and this fix resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

This fixed alt+arrow tty problem for me on ubuntu 18.04.2 with Firefox 66.0.3.