# How can I remap ALT+LEFT and ALT+RIGHT in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

These keys send me to terminal mode or UI mode and I want to change them because they interfere with development tools I use and dozens of years of motor memory. They just recently started doing this after an update. I would rather change them to Super+Left and Super+Right.

Answer (score 1):

See discussion here: [Why does alt+left arrow go into tty now? That's a chrome shortcut for 'back' and it keeps taking me to tty or login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060575/), and [the bug it links to](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146).

For me,
`sudo kbd_mode -s`
worked, but I've yet to see if it survives restarts (Edit: it does)