# Super + Left or Super + Right now switches TTY windows. How to prevent?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tty

Recently, pressing Super + Left or Super + Right started switching TTY terminals on my laptop. I have no clue why this is happening. In the gnome keyboard settings, this shortcut is assigned to move windows to the left or right side of the screen. It still does this behavior in addition to switching TTY terminals. I have no clue how it is doing this because as far as I know keyboard shortcuts normally only work while inside a gnome session.

How do I prevent this behavior?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tell me what commands to execute to get additional needed information.

Execution of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`:

```
['compose:caps']
```

Comment: can you share the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @PRATAP The output is `['compose:caps']`

Comment: i tried to reproduce the issue but could not.. in my case its working normal.. that is swap left and right with super+right arrow or left arrow

Comment: @PRATAP Yeah, it honestly just started happening recently. I have no clue what made it do that. Do you know of any other places that keyboard shortcuts are stored?

Comment: That causes (win or alt) + (left or right) to switch TTY while only alt + (left or right) causes snapping now

Comment: Hello, have same issue here on ubuntu 18.10, with budgie desktop. Just started happening last couple of weeks. Must have been something pushed out in software updates.

Comment: ... This seems to be a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060575/why-does-altleft-arrow-go-into-tty-now-thats-a-chrome-shortcut-for-back-and

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away on restart of the machine.